# What exactly is a defective nodal source

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, homogeneous-equation

[image]

I attain repeated root eigenvalue of $-1$ with eigenvector $\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}$

However, I'm uncertain if the general solution would be $c_1\cdot e^{-t}\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}$ alone, or would it be $c_1\cdot e^{-t}\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix} + c_2\cdot t\cdot e^{-t}\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Likewise, when I plot the phase portriat in software, I receive an alert claiming that the phase protriat is a defective nodal source. What is that exactly?

Comment: Your second attempt should be the right hence a general solution never consists only of one term. But I guess you need to rework the second eigenvector.

Comment: so I got my general solution as e^t(c1*(2;1)+c2(t(2;1)+(-4,0)). 

However, how can I solve this IVP with just one initial conditions and two arbitrary constants?

Comment: so I finalized my general solution to be e^t(c1(2,1)+c2(t(2,1)+(-4,0)) 

However, I do not understand how to solve the IVP with two constants unknown, and only one condition.

Comment: Since you are working on a system of differential equations there is no problem in calculating the constants. Just set the general solution equal to the IVP and split it up in two equations : now you got a linear system of two equations and two variables.

Comment: is my general solution correct to add the additional (-4,0) at the tail end of the problem?

Comment: Hi. I think the formatting is a little off

Comment: Finally : $\vec{x}~=~c_1\cdot e^{-t}\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}+c_2\left( t\cdot e^{-t}\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}+e^{-t}\begin{pmatrix}-4\\0\end{pmatrix}\right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of repeated real roots you need to calculate a different second eigenvector which  satisfies the equation

$$\begin{pmatrix}a-\lambda & b\\c & d-\lambda\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\rho_1\\\rho_2\end{pmatrix}~=~\begin{pmatrix}\eta_1\\\eta_2\end{pmatrix}$$

where $\begin{pmatrix}\eta_1\\\eta_2\end{pmatrix}$ is the first eigenvector and $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of the matrix. From there on you can conclude to the general solution of the form

$$\vec{x}~=~c_1\cdot e^{\lambda t}\vec{\eta}+c_2(t\cdot e^{\lambda t}\vec{\eta}+e^{\lambda t}\vec{\rho})$$

---

The eigenvalues of the given systems are the repeated real roots $\lambda_{1,2}=-1$. From there one you get the first eigenvector $\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}$ as you already did. Now just calculate the second eigenvector and you are done.

Comment: based on my general solution:
e^t(c1(2,1)+c2(t(2,1)+(-4,0)). 

Then if we use the IVP and plug in t = 0, I get (1,1) = c1(2,1) + c2(-4,0). I don't really understand how to isolate C1 and C2.

Comment: Just cosider it as a system of the two equations $1=c_1-4c_2$ and $1=-4c_1$

Comment: Based on the phase portrait of this particular case, can I argue that when t either moves to infinity or negative infinity, the phase portrait is moving tangentially inwards towards the origin.

Comment: Could you maybe link the phase potrait somewhere?

Comment: https://ibb.co/cDCyby

This is the phase portrait.

Comment: Yes, I guess you can argue like this and when I remebered it right there was something like fixed points connected with such eigenvalues. But I am sorry, I am not that familiar with phase portraits and how they work and what you can derive from them. But I got a good pdf right here concerning differential equations in general http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SystemsIntro.aspx

Comment: Or you could skip finding a generalized eigenvector and compute the exponential directly by exploiting the fact that the coefficient matrix decomposed into the sum of a diagonal and a nilpotent matrix.